# If new smart contract is created with same symbol or name, is there any way owner/creator can access new contract?

Tags: erc-20

I know of a situation where this was done, and somehow the creator /owner of last contract was able to transfer funds in new contract to several wallets. Was it because same symbol was used? Is there a function to RECALL transferred funds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If new smart contract is created with same symbol or name, is there any way owner/creator can access new contract?

Anyone can access any contract. It's an entirely different matter if the contract will approve requests or reject them. While ERC20 doesn't provide any assurance that there will be no duplication of symbols, duplicating a symbol doesn't unlock and any special privileges.

> I know of a situation where this was done, and somehow the creator /owner of last contract was able to transfer funds in new contract to several wallets.

No. Did not happen that way.

> Was it because same symbol was used?

No. Not a chance.

> Is there a function to RECALL transferred funds?

No.

It's not possible to be certain about anything based on the sparse facts provided. It's possible there was a case of mistaken identity or even deliberate phishing. None of the attack vectors mentioned are possible.

Hope it helps.